# Please explain how in the TSP, "every subpath of a path of minimum distance is itself a minimum distance"?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, dynamic-programming

According to wikipedia, and many other sources I have read through, the Held-Karp algorithm is based on the idea that "every subpath of a path of minimum distance is itself a minimum distance."

I was hoping someone could explain this concept to me, because that claim doesn't seem true to me at all.  If every subpath was a minimum distance, then that would mean that every pair of edges (3 connected cities) would itself be a minimum distance, which would mean that those are simply the two best edges connected to each other, which would also mean that a basic greedy algorithm would output an optimal TSP circuit every time.

So, clearly I am missing something conceptually.  Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every subpath in a path of minimum distance is a path of minimum distance between the endpoints of the subpath.   For example if $a \to b \to c \to d \to e$ is a path of minimum distance from $a$ to $e$, then $b \to c \to d$ must be a path of minimum distance from $b$ to $d$.  This is because if, say, $b \to c' \to d$ was a shorter path from $b$ to $d$, you could substitute this for $b \to c \to d$ in your original path, giving you $a \to b \to c' \to d \to e$ which is shorter than $a \to b \to c \to d \to e$.

This doesn't mean that a greedy algorithm works.  In a greedy approach, starting from $a$, you might start with an edge of shortest distance $a \to z$.  But maybe $z$ is farther from your goal than some of the other possible alternatives for the first step.

Comment: Ah ok, so that's what it is talking about.  I feel that is a little misleading, because what it should say is every subpath of a path of minimum distance is itself a minimum distance - *when constrained to only using the nodes within that subpath*, not within the span of our entire graph.

Comment: This is within the span of the entire graph - for instance $c'$ was not in the path, and was instead in the rest of the graph.

Comment: The principle is true for shortest paths in general.  In the context of TSP, you apply it to subpaths from $a$ to $b$ involving a given set of vertices.